# Expression to make image same height as shape

Tags: after-effects-expressions

I have a shape that varies in height, and an image that varies in height.

I would like the image height to be the same height as the shape at all times.

I got as far as this, but none of my math seems to be making the image the same height as the bar constantly.

```
kyronnb = thisComp.layer("Kyron BG").sourceRectAtTime();

syz = 100 * thisLayer.height/thisComp.height - 100; 
kper = 100 * kyronnb.height/thisComp.height;

sizeW = kper - syz;

[sizeW, sizeW]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "Kyron BG" is the shape layer and thisLayer is the image layer and you're applying the expression on the scaling of the image layer. Then this should work:

```
kyronnb = thisComp.layer("Kyron BG").sourceRectAtTime();
scaleFactor = kyronnb.height/thisLayer.height*100;
[scaleFactor, scaleFactor]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! So simple.